# How to animate height of Bootstrap 4 Carousel with items of different heights?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have tried a few React components to animate height, with no success.
I don't want to use jQuery as some solutions propose, and I hope to find a solution using Bootstrap's own Collapse animation utilities or vanilla JS/CSS.

Comment: Try adding a css transition https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: I need to pin this style on the div (carousel-inner?) which is resizing in height in the event of carousel-item slide in, and it seems like none of the parent div is explicitly changing height. Can you please check?

Comment: Check what? You haven't added any code.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Here is the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-water-lgxwk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi, have you tied the demo and found a solution?